# Need help in fixing sql connection issue using service account though pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

When I try to run the below code I am getting following error. Tried referring other posts but it does not seem to help.

The server principal "{Myuser}" is not able to access the database "{database}" under the current security context. (916) (SQLExecDirectW)'

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      'Server=XXXXXXX;'
                      'Port=xxxx'
                      'Username={service_account}'
                      'Password={password of service_account}'
                      'Database={detabase};'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

results = cnxn.cursor()

results.execute('SELECT * FROM {database}.dbo.{tablename}')

for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Comment: it seems that you need to pass actual values in your connection string.

Comment: I have passed actual values, i have masked them for the security purpose.

Comment: my guess is that it is taking windows authentication rather than sql server authentication, since {Myuser} is my user name rather than the value passed in 'Username={service_account}'

Comment: If you pass a user/pass - the trusted connection option shouldn't be set to true; that would override the user/pass and use your windows credentials.

Comment: removing 'Trusted_Connection=yes;' or changing to 'Trusted_Connection=false;' is giving the same result.

Comment: I'll leave this for the python experts then... the connection string above doesn't look properly formatted to me (based on a 2 minute google search), but I'm not familiar enough with python to say that concretely, yet it *does* seem you're hitting SQL Server.  The error is pretty clear from SQL -- the wrong user seems to be in use.  Are you missing ; after each item perhaps?  Or is that a result of over editing?

Comment: when i use cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      'Server=XXXXXXX;'
                      'Port=xxxx;'
                      'Username={service_account};'
                      'Password={password of service_account};'
                      'Database={detabase};'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')   I get General network error. Check your network documentation

Comment: Dave- appreciate your time on this, can you please upvote this questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use Microsoft's ODBC driver for SQL Server and `Trusted_Connection=yes` (SQL Server Windows authentication) then you don't pass the Windows credentials in the connection string. Instead, you run your Python app as the Windows user. Ways to do that include

- launching the Python app from a Windows command prompt using the `RUNAS` command, or
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>right_clicking your app's icon, then choose "Run as different user".

Another option might be to use the FreeTDS ODBC driver. It supports the older NTLM authentication protocol and allows you to specify the DOMAIN, UID, and PWD (for Windows authentication) in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import pyodbc 
password = "<password>"
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=<host>;Port=<port>;UID= 
<username>;PWD=" + password + ";Database=<dbname>;")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM <table>')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```